# What does printf("\033c" ) mean?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, console, printf

I was looking for a way to "reset" my Unix terminal window after closing my program, and stumbled upon `printf("\033c" );` which works perfectly, but I just can't understand it. I went to `man console_codes` and since I'm somewhat inexperienced with Unix c programming, it wasn't very helpful.

Could someone explain `printf("\033c" );`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In C numbers starting with a leading zero are [*octal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers. Numbers in base 8.

What it does is print the character represented by octal number `33` followed by a `'c'`.

In [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) the octal number `33` is the `ESC` (escape) character, which is a common prefix for terminal control sequences.

With that knowledge searching for terminal control sequences we can find e.g. [this VT100 control sequence reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624214929/http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) ([VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) was an old "dumb" terminal, and is emulated by most modern terminal programs). Using the VT100 reference we find `<ESC>c` in the terminal setup section, where it's documented as

> **Reset Device        `<ESC>c`**
>
> Reset all terminal settings to default.

---

The `ESC` character could also be printed using `"\x1b"` (still assuming ASCII encoding). There is no way to use decimal numbers in constant string literals, only octal and hexadecimal.

***However*** (as noted by [the comment by chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503734/what-does-printf-033c-mean/47503782?noredirect=1#comment81963534_47503782)) the sequence `"\x1bc"` will *not* do the same as `"\033c"`. That's because `0x1bc` is a valid hexadecimal number, and the compiler is *greedy* when it parses such sequences. It will print the character represented by the value `0x1bc` instead, and I have no idea what it might be (depends on locale and terminal settings I suppose, might be printed as a Unicode character).

Comment: Well i don't think a better answer exists! Thanks a lot for not only instructing me in something new but also providing a more correct answer.

Comment: Minor: `"\x1bc"` may not give the same result as `"\033c"` as the hex escape is not clearly length limited.  Could use `"\x1b" "c"`

Comment: @chux Proof that even experience doesn't mean everything sometimes. And that "code" reviews *do* help. :)

Comment: Decimal number: `printf("%cc", 27);` :)

Comment: @rici Well yes, but that's not in a *string literal* :)

Comment: *"and the printf function is greedy when it reads characters"* Character escape sequences are resolved at compile time, not by `printf` function.

Answer (score 8):

That's an escape sequence used to **reset** a DEC VT100 (or compatible) terminal.  Some terminals (such as Linux console) accept VT100-style escape sequences, even when they are not actually VT100s.

The **`\033`** is the ASCII escape character, which begins these sequences. Most are followed by another special character (this is a rare exception).  [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Controls-beginning-with-ESC) lists that, along with others that are not followed by a special character.

In ECMA-48 it is possible to use a different character for the usual case, e.g., **`[`** for the *control sequence initiator.

Resetting a real VT100 (in contrast to a terminal emulator) does more than clear the screen, as noted in *[Debian Bug report logs - #60377
"reset" broken for dumb terminals](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=60377)*, but users of terminal emulators tend to assume it is a short way to clear the screen.  The standard way would be something like this:

```
printf("\033[H\033[J");
```

The ncurses FAQ *[Why does reset log me out?](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#reset_logout)* addresses that issue.

Incidentally, users of terminal emulators also get other issues with the terminal confused.  The ncurses FAQ *[How do I get color with VT100?](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)* addresses one of those.

Comment: Thanks for your response! With the answer Some Programmer Dude provided the terminal, after "clearing" would stick mid way instead of at the top left corner like it should, and my OCD kicked in so i had to stick with `033c`. But yours actually does the same, without the possible issues you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

It clears the screen in Linux type operating systems (ubuntu, fedora etc...).
You can check here on [asciitable.com](https://www.asciitable.com/), under octal 33 (decimal 27) you have ESC character.